# Calc percentage in IE11

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

Is there any way to make the css `calc` function work with an offset like below in IE11?

This doesn't work in IE11:

```
div:nth-child(1) {
  background: hsl(114.54545, 44%, calc(55.88235% * 1.1));
}
```

A static percentage does:

```
div:nth-child(2) {
  background: hsl(114.54545, 44%, 55.88235%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d5hoe102/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to approximate it using an extra white layer to increase the lightness whithout the need of `calc()`

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
  background: hsl(114.54545, 44%, calc(55.88235% * 1.1));
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background: hsl(114.54545, 44%, 55.88235%);
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
div:nth-child(2):before {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 z-index:-1;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); 
}
```

```html
<div>calc</div>
<div>static</div>
```

You can also do it with multiple background:

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
  background: hsl(114.54545, 44%, calc(55.88235% * 1.1));
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1),rgba(255,255,255,0.1)),
    hsl(114.54545, 44%, 55.88235%); 
}
```

```html
<div>calc</div>
<div>static</div>
```